Gurps ritual path magic for seeing ghosts in a prerecorded video
In many fantasy settings, ghosts and some other creatures are invisible on cameras or videos. I want to come up with a Gurps Thaumatology: Ritual Path Magic spell to take a pre-existing recording of an occasion where a ghost was present (e.g. from a cctv camera) and make the ghost reappear on the video.
I am imagining a cost like below, but I am unsure if I should be using any modifiers here. Should it be more expensive to reveal a more powerful spirit than an everyday poltergeist?
Keen to hear your thoughts.
Reveal the invisible:
Lesser Transform Matter (8)
Greater Sense Chance [for divination effect] (2)
Greater Sense Undead (2)
Base cost = 12*5 = 60 energy
Modifiers
Time (for how old the video or photograph is)
Duration (for how long the modification on the video lasts)

You have an assumptions problem here. The question is if the recording contains any kind of latent or hidden information about the ghost? If it does, then you can reveal it. If not, then you need to look back in time with a sense that can detect the ghost and adding it to the videotape is only a means of displaying the information. It still might be useful for impressing people, but it doesn't make the magic any easier.

Yeah there's some in-universe metaphysics to think of here. Why are ghosts visible to the  eye but not cameras? However, for an RPG I'd motivate this operating assumption for a) being cool and b) having narrative value: if the players can find a Thing (in this case the tape/image) they can learn a Clue. That seems better to me than saying 'forget the footage just look back in time silly'.
